# Incorrect return address is POPed after SVC call

Tags: assembly, arm, stack, abort, cortex-a

I am working on an ARM Cortex-A5 core of a custom processor and getting a really weird issue which seem to be unexplainable from the SW point of view.
 The issue is that at some point when *stress-testing* the system (rebooting hundreds of times), sometimes a Prefetch abort is happening when returning from some SVC call. The calls are implemented as following:

User mode code:

```
;...Stuff
    BL       foo
;.. Stuff.

foo
    PUSH     {r4,lr}
    SVC      #0x1a 
    POP      {r4,pc}
```

SVC handler:

```
SVC_Handler
    PUSH     {r0-r12,lr}
    ;... Do stuff
    POP      {r0-r12,lr}
    SUBS     pc,lr,#0
```

When the abort is happening, the `LR_USR` is pointing to the instruction next to `BL foo`, but `IFAR` has a value of zero as well as `r4`. So is `LR_ABT` has a value of `0x4`, which makes sense if we tried to branch to the address zero. Given these observations it looks like the `POP {r4,pc}` instruction is fetching two zeros from the stack instead of the correct values, **which are in the stack at the correct positions** as observed with the debugger **after** the abort is hit (they are two words above the `SP_USR`). So it looks like either the stack is updated with the correct values *after* the pop instruction is happening, or the `POP` instruction is just buggy.

It worth noting that the code and the stack are in a cacheable memory. User mode and SVC mode have distinct stacks.

Can this effect be explained from the SW point of view or it is likely a hardware bug (memory/cache controller?). Have anyone seen something similar in their career? Unfortunately it is possible to debug only *post-mortem*. And instrumenting the code is shifting the bug away to another call (Yes, it is Heisenbug...)

Comment: Why are you modifying pc this way? What about bx lr?

Comment: This is a completely legitimate way to return from a function according to Arm docs. And what is more important, it is how the `armcc` compiler is generating it :)

Comment: you are convinced that the problem is with the code or the arm core and not the chip you are testing?  prefetch aborts come from the processor bus, generated by the not ARM logic.  What is going on in that logic at this time?

Comment: `SVC_Handler` has somehow change the `spsr` and is not returning to the correct mode is a possibility.  Did you check the `cpsr` where you have the `LR_ABT` which should be `spsr_abt`?

Comment: @old_timer I am pretty convinced at this point the problem is *not* with the code, but posted it here to get even more convinced :) But yeah, unfortunately the system is pretty complex, but theoretically this specific part should be transparent for the ARM core. Prefetch abort seems to be very logical given the return address is just bad. The question is why it is bad.

Comment: @artlessnoise I will give it another look when back to the desk, but I am pretty sure it was indicating Usr mode...

Comment: Yes I have worked on chips in my career, currently do, per your question.  And a prefetch abort can come from the axi/amba bus meaning not related to the core. a breakpoint instruction (would have to somehow magically change some other instruction and/or if you have one somewhere the axi/amba/memory system can get confused or corrupt and return the wrong data for the fetch.  Or it could be something in the core, do you have the source code for the chip can you run a sim?

Comment: what if you slow down the clocks?  are you using dram? is your dram refreshing correctly?  is the cache on does it happen with the cache off?  are you running an operating system can you target the problem without that, how little software does it take to fault.  How often does it fault.  within seconds, minutes, hours?  does it happen on every chip, or only certain chips, does it happen on every board or only certain boards?

Comment: do you have alternate memory?  internal sram vs external dram?  does it fail if you change memory systems?

Comment: @old_timer It's a OS spanning across Normal and Secure worlds.. Svc code is and stack are running from Sam and User mode code and stack is in DRAM. Which gave me an idea when typing. I know DRAM can enter some kind of low power state when not accessed. So it could be the case that after some time Svc is running in SRAM, DRAM is going to to sleep. And not waking up properly on the first access attempt at some instances... Will bring this idea to our HW folks..

Comment: yeah so that is going to make it that much harder to figure out...(only breaking on an os).  maybe walk the stacks and see what code was running before the fault.  maybe there is a pattern.  one board/chip or many?

Comment: is this a hard arm core in an fpga?  or the whole chip is custom?

Comment: Do you have access to ETM trace? Not sure it will show a lot, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: @old_timer We have an incomplete model on FPGA, but yeah, it is ASIC. Unfortunately it is unlikely that we would be able to emulate the full system  on it. Currently I wen't to the idea of the DRAM not waking up properly, performing some experiments..

Comment: @SeanHoulihane Unfortunately the ETM trace is not implemented on this ASIC..

Comment: I think it could definitely be an issue with TrustZone and secure/normal with banked CP15 and secure/no-secure cache entries.  There is a lot of possible SW issues with the system you describe before I would say it is hardware.